# Required property not found in json

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm trying to make a field mandatory before submitting to the server. For this I used the **[Required]** data annotation for the model validation. It work as expected for the **string** data types but not for a **double**.

For some reason it's not working for the **double** type property. 
Here is the code that I have for the **model**:

```
public class ProductMetadata
{
    [Required]
    public string Barcode { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage="Please insert the product name!")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Range(0, 5000)]
    public double ShippingCostPerUnit { get; set; }

    [Range(0, 10000)]
    public int QuantityForFreeShipping { get; set; }

    public Nullable<int> CategoryId { get; set; }

    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    [Range(0, 1000000)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please provide a unit price for the product!")]
    public double UnitPrice { get; set; }
}
```

The response body is a JSON response and for none of the required fields completed has the following content:

```
{
 "Message":"The request is invalid.",
 "ModelState":
            {"product":["Required property 'UnitPrice' not found in JSON. Path '', line 1, position 33."],
             "product.Barcode":["The Barcode field is required."],
             "product.Name":["Please insert the product name!"]
            }
}
```

I don't understand why is working fine for the **Name** and **Barcode** and not for **UnitPrice**.

**Edit 1**:

If I remove the **[Required]** attribute and I put the input for the **UnitPrice** -1 I receive the appropriate validation message, so why is not working for the **Required** attribute?

**Edit 2**: The request payload(also updated the **ProductMetadata** class):

```
{IsDelete: false, CategoryId: 1}
CategoryId: 1
IsDelete: false
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Can you share your request payload - JSON?

Comment: @Paritosh I have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

The fastest decision is to make Unit Price nullable

```
[Range(0, 1000000)]
[Required(ErrorMessage="Please provide a unit price for the product!")]
public double? UnitPrice { get; set; }
```

The problem is the field Unit Price is missing in json and JSON Formatter tries to deserialize double and receives exception before Required is executed.